# why is my slds-grid not fitting to page?

Tags: apex, lightning-datatable, datatable, slds-grid

I have a datatable inside of a slds-grid so that I can have multiple tables side by side. When I do this though, the LWC does not fit to the page. Is there a tag I am missing that will enforce strict positioning?

```
<template if:true={ready}>
    <lightning-card id="mainForm">
    <lightning-card ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main" class="mb30">
      ...other code in here that is not relevant
     <div class="slds-grid">
         <template for:each={ml.Childs} for:item="month">
             <div key={month} class="slds-col">
                <lightning-datatable 
                  key={month} 
                   key-field="id" 
                   hide-table-header 
                   hide-checkbox-column 
                   show-row-number-column
                   data={month.DaysInMonthList}
                   columns={columns}>
                 </lightning-datatable>
             </div>
          </template>
       </div>
```

[image]

*I have also tried doing just a html table with flex-box css and still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up breaking out the data table into a HTML table and it worked fine. There must be some css attached to the slds-col or datatable that were in direct conflict with the rest of the page's css.